# Android activity go back to activity that started it instead of parent activity when pressing navigation bar back button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, parent, back

I have the following scenario:

In android manifest I have three activities:
ActivityA
ActivityB - parent of ActivityA
ActivityC

What I want to do is start ActivityA from ActivityC using intent.StartActivity(). The activity is started successfully. Now I want to go back to ActivityC using actionbar's back button (upper left corner), but since ActivityA has ActivityB as parent (as declared in android manifest) the actionbar back button takes me to ActivityB instead of previous ActivityC. If I use the back keyboard button, I get redirected to the ActivityC.

What can I do to get the same result in both "navigate back" cases. The result I'm seeking is to get redirected to the activity that started the ActivityA and not it's parent activity. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you really need to set B as parent of A?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should not define ActivityB as parent for ActivityA in manifest. Instead, handle onOptionsItemSelected in ActivityA like this:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
        }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: So, you mean that if an activity has a parent activity defined in manifest using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP does not "override" that setting?

Comment: do you know why Android doesn't do <code>switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
        }</code> by default

Comment: What I meant to say was: if pressing in upper left corner in Activity A does not always take you to Activity B, then Activity B is not logically a parent of Activity A. Therefore you should not define it as a parent in manifest. Otherwise you'll have problems like what you are experiencing now.

As to the default code question - not every activity has enabled touching for upper left corner, so it would not be a code that is always useful.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the clarification. I removed the parent definition for the Activity A and handled the "onOptionsItemSelected()" for "android.R.id.home" just like in your code. But I'm facing a weird behavior: by pressing the upper left corner (navigate back button) the Acitivty B is recreated as opposed to pressing the back button of the phone (hardware back button), which does not recreate Activity B (it's layout is exactly as before navigation to Activity A). I've also tried "return true;" after calling "finish();" for "case android.R.id.home:" - same result. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please add manifest declaration for your Activity A and Activity B to your question. I suspect there might be something there that's causing the new problem.

Comment: <activity
 android:name="com.example.myapplication2.ActivityB"
 android:label="@string/title_activity_b" >
</activity>
<activity
 android:name="com.example.myapplication2.ActivityA"
 android:label="@string/title_activity_a"
 android:parentActivityName="com.example.myapplication2.ActivityB" >
 <meta-data
  android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
  android:value="com.example.myapplication2.ActivityB" />
</activity>

Comment: Try using `<activity android:name="com.example.myapplication2.ActivityB" android:label="@string/title_activity_b" > </activity> <activity android:name="com.example.myapplication2.ActivityA" android:label="@string/title_activity_a" > </activity>` instead

Comment: I see. You suggest that I should remove the parent definition from the child activity... Do you know why android recreates the parent activity if navigating back with upper the left corner touch and doesn't do that if user presses the phone's back button? As per your suggested solution this behavior might be avoided. Can you explain why?

Comment: Setting the parent activity in xml is just a shortcut for implementing an activity navigation pattern that can be replicated in code. I've not used the xml setting myself and my thinking towards using it is like this - try it, but if it does not suit your needs, just implement navigation in code.

Comment: Ok. Removed the parent definition from manifest xml and implemented navigation in code `Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityA.class); startActivity(intent);`. The code is inside a class that implements Fragment (support library v7). The result is the same: back navigation from upper left corner recreates the previous activity's layout; that is not happening if I navigate from the phone's back button. Very confusing...

Comment: To implement navigation in code you should use the code I provided. Calling `finish()` is the same as user pressing back button.

Answer (score 3):

When you call startActivity(), do it like that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(callingActivity.this, destinationActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;  
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This will emulate a back button press, which will additionally preserve the state of the `Activity` you came from (tabs, scroll position).

(Credit goes to @Kise for suggesting this in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31331757/2703209)