# Android Navigate Back to Activity; Don't Reload Parent

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a scenario where I am clicking on a ListFragment and spinning up a new Activity like below:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), VenueBeerActivity.class);
  Parcelable wrapped = Parcels.wrap(mAdapter.getItem(position));
  intent.putExtra("venue", wrapped);

  startActivity(intent);
}
```

This works fine and displays the new activity.

I've modified this activities manifest so it points back to its parent activity (in this case main activity)

However the problem I have is when the back button is pressed, it reloads the entire parent. The parent is a list and I don't want it to reload the users position. How can I prevent this?

As a note. The parent houses a Page Tab Strip.

I'm sure this is a relatively simple fix...

Comment: Someone posted then deleted their post.. but it lead to me to what I believe is what I need!         android:launchMode="singleInstance"

Comment: Your first activity can be destroyed while in background and has to be recreated. You have to handle this...

Answer (score 11):

What do you mean by "back button"? Is it the up button in the toolbar? If that's the case, edit the `onOptionsItemSelected` in your `VenueBeerActivity` to:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;  
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

So when user press the Up button it will get the behavior of the back button in the navigation bar.

Comment: This saved my day! Had this problem with a SimpleAdapter, saw all kinds of answers to save state, nothing really worked well or seemed to be an overkill. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In the parent activity, set the `android:launchMode` attribute to `singleTop`. This would prevent the system from creating a new instance of parent when up button is pressed.

Comment: Im using android navigation, this doesnt seem to solve the problem